I am getting a PostgreSql error when try to run this 'Copy table' on my Mac desktop folder by running this command
I am getting a PostgreSql error when try to run this 'Copy table' on my Mac desktop folder by running this command;
COPY char_data_types TO 'myfilePathToMac'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER '|');

Tryin to COPY a table save it to my desktop folder on Mac and getting an error 'ERROR:  could not open file.
SQL state: 42809

Apparently, the account that the database engine runs under doesn't have the proper permissions to write to myfilePathToMac.

Reading the docs COPY is a good place to start: COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read from or write to a file. The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server.

Thank for comment. I create a tmp file through the terminal on Mac for testing and it works though I am still having permission to direct write.

Server side COPY statement with file as target can be used only by superuser. All others users can use only stdin, stdout targets. The target file should be accessed by system user postgres. Attention - COPY is server side command, and the location of target file is on server with Postgres.

Thank for comment. I create a tmp file through the terminal on Mac for testing and it works though I am still having permission to direct write.
